# CSS select only first child in an unordered list

Tags: css, selector

I have the following code in my wordpress theme:

```
<div class="BlaBla">
   <ul>
       <li>
          <a>stuff to select</a>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a>stuff to NOT select</a>
       </li>
   <\ul>
</div>
```

i have to select the first "a" tag to remove it (add the rule display: none) but i can't put id's or classes

i tried the following rules but select every things

```
div[class="BlaBla"] ul li a:first-child{
    display:none;
}

div[class="BlaBla"] ul li:first-child{
    display:none;
}

div[class="BlaBla"] > ul > li:first-child{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to target the link inside the first `list-item` so the selector is

```
.BlaBla li:first-child a {
  display: none;
}
```

About your attempted solutions:

- the first one will target all the first links inside *all* the list-items
- the second one will target the first list-item (and *not* the link inside the first list-item)
- the last one uses the child combinator and, in your example, works exactly as in the second attempt.